# Inner widgets disappear after page reload

Tags: javascript, apostrophe-cms

I am having an issue with my nested widgets. There's two widget container (full-width and TwoColumn), which share pretty much same code for configurations but different html code; as well as, 4 different types of widgets that are nested inside any of the previous containers.

So, I can create any type of container and it sill remain on the page. However, only nested widgets in full-width container get saved. Meaning that if I reload the page, the content of TwoColumn containers, is missing.

Please find below code for both containers:

**Full-width**

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  label: 'Row Block',
  contextualOnly: true,
  addFields: [
    {
      type: 'area',
      name: 'row',
      label: 'row',
      contextual: true
    }
  ],
  construct: function(self, options) {
    var superPushAssets = self.pushAssets;
    self.pushAssets = function() {
      superPushAssets();
      self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'always', { when: 'always' });
    };
  }
};
```

**TwoColumn**

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  label: 'Two column row Block',
  contextualOnly: true,
  addFields: [
    {
      type: 'area',
      name: 'twoColumnRow',
      label: 'twoColumnRow',
      contextual: true
    }
  ],
  construct: function(self, options) {
    var superPushAssets = self.pushAssets;
    self.pushAssets = function() {
      superPushAssets();
      self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'always', { when: 'always' });
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: Any browser or server side errors in the console?

Comment: Nothing shows up in the console.

Comment: Can you post the templates of each of the widgets?

Comment: It sounds like you're pretty far down the road but it might be worth double checking this recently published tutorial on the subject .. might help you spot a bug http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/layout-widgets.html